# Does Time.to_i always return number of seconds since EPOCH in UTC?

Tags: ruby, time, timezone, ruby-1.9, epoch

Is the timezone difference always ignored, regardless in which zone the time is expressed in?

Intuitively, the number of seconds passed since EPOCH should be higher for those who are, for example, in UTC+2. However, this seems not to be the case.

Comment: How are you getting the Time object? You can't call to_i on the Time class. If you use Time.now.to_i it'll be the current time zone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Epoch is based on the utc timezone https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time
it does not depend of the timezone you're currently in.

Comment: So, it is true that `Time.now.to_i == Time.now.utc.to_i` is ALWAYS `true`